# how to give link between two parts of a singe web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have divided my web page into two parts using div tag. Left part is 20% and right part is 80%. I have given links in the left side part,when I click on that link it should display the matter in the right part. Can you please tell me how it is possible with div??

Comment: do you have some code? can you put it ?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

     <div class="row">
      <div class="4u">
      <a href="#content1">Click here to modify content</a>
<ul>
 <li>
 <a href="C:/Program Files/RUNNING.txt" target="middle">Config(.ini) 1.1</a>
 </li>
</ul>
   </div>
   </div>
   
 <div class="8u">
 <div id="content1"></div>
 
 </div>      
 </body>
</html>

Comment: iam trying with this simple code..bt im not able to display the text file information in the right side..can u please help me??

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, your left part is short and right part is long that you can scroll the page. You can use anchors to navigate. On the right side, put anchors like

```
<a name="section1"/>
```

where you want to stop, there will be no href attribute. On the left side link will be like this:

```
<a href="#section1">Go to section 1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an id for the right side div. And call that id using a href in left side links.

```
<a href="#content1">Click here to modify content</a>

<div id="content1">Your content here</div>
```

Check it out in:http://jsfiddle.net/hema765/LAdfN/3/

Comment: I tried with that,bt it is not displaying information wt i gave the file path in the left side link..hw can i get that file inf in the right side????

Comment: It is text file nly..if  i click on that link,that text file information displaying in the seperate page.

Comment: Can u add some sample code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> <title>Insert title here</title> </head> <body> <div class="row"> <div class="4u"> <a href="#content1">Click here to modify content</a> <ul> <li> <a href="C:/Program Files/RUNNING.txt" target="middle">Config(.ini) 1.1</a> </li> </ul> </div> </div> <div class="8u"> <div id="content1"></div> </div> </body> </html>

Comment: im giving file path frm my local machine

Comment: i gave class==8u naa..in that part it should display the text file information..

Comment: You need to show the content which is inside the "content1" div right?But why hadn't you put the txt file in that div?

Comment: Check out in the fiddle for sample:http://jsfiddle.net/hema765/LAdfN/embedded/result/

Comment: noo... i need to diaplay the file infrmation..it shd take the file from local machine and it shd display it..

Comment: how to put that txt file in the right side div??

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#Comehere"> Click to go the Part </a>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div><div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="go"> Part 1 </div>
<div id="Comehere"> Hi this is the part </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Comehere
{
    display:block;
    margin:50px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background-color:#003366;
    color:white;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gamta/5/)